# How to set constant seeds for Haskell's quickCheck function

Tags: testing, haskell, random, quickcheck

Every time I run "quickCheck prop_xyz", a new random seed is used. How do I enforce QuickCheck to always use the same random seed?

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask why you want to? If you want repeatable tests, a good shrink implementation is far more useful. The whole point here is to be random so a constant seeds defeats that

Comment: @jozefg: I know we've found it useful in the past when you want to evaluate how your generators, etc., are performing.

Comment: @jozefg: We are running some experiments using QuickCheck and want to reproduce our results. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functionality you need is in [`Test.QuickCheck`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html); use [`quickCheckWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v%3aquickCheckWith) to specify custom [`Args`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t%3aArgs).  In particular, there's the [`replay :: Maybe (StdGen, Int)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v%3areplay) field, which allows you to replay tests.  So you can use the [`stdArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v%3astdArgs) defaults and tweak them; for instance,

```
ghci> :load Main.hs
ghci> import Test.QuickCheck
ghci> import System.Random -- for mkStdGen
ghci> quickCheckWith stdArgs{replay = Just (mkStdGen 42, 0)} prop_xyz
```

The second component of the tuple has to do with the size of the test cases, but I forget exactly what.

Comment: It's `Test.QuickCheck.Random.mkQCGen` in recent version(s?).

Comment: As @SebastianGraf alludes to, you need the a Test.QuickCheck.Random.QCGen, not a System.Random.StdGen. It isn't listed on hackage, but Test.QuickCheck.Random exposes mkQCGen which serves the same purpose as mkStdGen.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `quickCheckWith` function

```
quickCheckWith (stdArgs{replay = Just (myNewGen, testSize)}) property
```

If you have a test that's failing and you want to reuse it,

```
result <- quickCheckResult failing_prop
let gen = usedSeed result
let size = usedSize result
```

to get the size and seed used in a failing test.

Since you also want reproducible errors, a good shrinking algorithm may help. By default it returns `[]` but provide a nice enough one, then you can end up with the same (minimal) failures even on different random runs.

Answer (score 1):

Example with QuickCheck >= 2.7 and tf-random.

If the output of your failing test run looks something like this:

```haskell
Failure {
    usedSeed = TFGenR 1CE4E8B15F9197B60EE70803C62388671B62D6F88720288F5339F7EC521FEBC4 0 70368744177663 46 0,
    USEDSIZE = 75,
    ...        
}
```

Then you can reproduce the failure as follows:

```haskell
import Test.QuickCheck.Random (QCGen(..))
import System.Random.TF (TFGen)

qcheck :: Testable a => a -> IO ()
qcheck prop = quickCheckWith args prop
    where
        usedSeed = QCGen (read "TFGenR 1CE4E8B15F9197B60EE70803C62388671B62D6F88720288F5339F7EC521FEBC4 0 70368744177663 46 0"::TFGen)
        usedSize = 75
        args = stdArgs{
            replay=Just(usedSeed, usedSize)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine the `Generator` that caused the failure you could do the following:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import System.Random


reproducableTest :: Testable a => a -> Maybe (StdGen, Int) -> IO ()
reproducableTest prop repl = do result <- quickCheckWithResult stdArgs{replay = repl} prop
                                case result of
                                     Failure{interrupted = False} -> do putStrLn $ "Use " ++ show (usedSeed result) ++ " as the initial seed"
                                                                        putStrLn $ "Use " ++ show (usedSize result) ++ " as the initial size"
                                     _       -> return ()
```

Only the first of the two seed numbers should be used as an argument for the function.
So if you have your property `prop`, your initial call would be `reproducableTest prop Nothing`. You will get something like

```
  Use x y as the initial seed
  Use z as the initial size
```

Then you would call again with `reproducableTest prop $ Just (mkStdGen x , z)`

Comment: It would be better to use `read "x y" :: StdGen`, since `show (mkStdGen 42) == "43 1"`.  (`read` and `show` are guaranteed to behave properly here.)